# Halo CE installation help

Tags: wine, games, 17.10

So I have Halo CE on my laptop and it seemed to install properly, yet I get this message when I boot the game up: [image]
 Did I do something wrong in the installation process?  Is Wine only using a portion of my graphics?  This is on Wine 2.0.3 Thanks and regards,
Thomas

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu or Debian? Also, this seems likely to be a bug in Wine or you may need to install direct3d under wine.

Comment: I am running this on lightdm to conserve battery life.  Traditionally I use budgie, but this runs much quicker on low power.  I also have Directx 9 Installed...although from the likes of it, it seems like a different thing

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with the `-windowed` argument- it worked for me after this.

```
wine haloce.exe -windowed
```